# Output de np.where só retrona um valor

Tags: python, numpy, input-output

Estou desenvolvendo um código para me ajudar a analisar planilhas de importação de uma forma mais rápida e melhor do que as ferramentas que o excel oferece.

Basicamente, eu pego uma planilha, converto para CSV e importo pandas e numpy para analisar os dados.

Estou focando a análise no uso do np.where:

Bibliotecas utilizadas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Upload da base de dados CSV e isolando a coluna que tenho interesse em trabalhar

```
database = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CaiqueBarrreto/agroci/main/basePY.csv?token=ALHIP5CKNZG5LXZUVMQPAMLADLQGM")
database_goodshipped = database.iloc[:,[26]]
```

A etapa crítica agora é transformar a coluna 26 dessa base em uma lista e analisar as strings de cada linha dela, retornando um valor condicional em outra coluna:

```
conteudo = [database_goodshipped]
df = pd.DataFrame({"dados_de_compra": conteudo})
df['variavel_resposta'] = np.where(df['dados_de_compra'].str.contains('FLUTRIAFOL'),
                               'FLUTRIAFOL', 'NID')
df
```

Basicamente, eu quero que ele me retorne numa outra coluna a expressão 'FLUTRIAFOL' se ele encontrar esta expressão em qualquer linha da coluna que estou analisando (que no caso foi convertida na lista 'conteúdo')

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou confuso e não sei o que poderia estar havendo para o código não estar trabalhando para todas as linhas, uma vez que são quase 3k ítens na lista 'conteúdo' que criei e com certeza tem mais de uma linha contendo o 'FLUTRIAFOL'

Comment: O link para o csv não está funcionando

Comment: por algum motivo ele expira em pouco tempo e eu tenho que ficar atualizando.... segue outro:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CaiqueBarrreto/agroci/main/basePY.csv?token=ALHIP5GRZSSWEF5TWSX4AX3ADLSPW

Comment: sem acesso de novo

Comment: puts... desculpe. Não sei ainda como fazer para ele não expirar, Paulo. Obrigado pela paciencia. Acho que agora deve ir, fiz um ajuste no github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CaiqueBarrreto/agroci/main/basePY.csv?token=ALHIP5HTMLLMRGZFZRHVIYTADLT6C

Comment: O erro é `404: Not Found`. O repositório é privado ou público?

Comment: era privado... tornei ele publico agora. Deve funcionar desta vez: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CaiqueBarrreto/agroci/main/basePY.csv

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma forma...

### Carrega variáveis

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

### Cria dataframe

```
database = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CaiqueBarrreto/agroci/main/basePY.csv?token=ALHIP5CKNZG5LXZUVMQPAMLADLQGM")
database_goodshipped = database.iloc[:,[26]]
```

### Cria nova coluna usando np.where

```
database_goodshipped["variavel_resposta"] = np.where(database_goodshipped['Goods Shipped'].str.contains('FLUTRIAFOL'), 'FLUTRIAFOL', 'NID')
```

**Nota** Vc pode receber um *warning* como o abaixo... Mas funciona

```
<stdin>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

### Outra opcao

```
database_goodshipped["nova_coluna"] = database_goodshipped['Goods Shipped'].apply(lambda row: 'FLUTRIAFOL' if 'FLUTRIAFOL' in row else 'NID')
```

O resultado

```
>>> database_goodshipped
                                          Goods Shipped variavel_resposta nova_coluna
0     15 X 20 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 300 BAGS OF 2,4-...               NID         NID
1     4 X 40 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 160 BAGS OF CARBE...               NID         NID
2     1 X 40 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 40 BAGS OF FLUTRI...        FLUTRIAFOL  FLUTRIAFOL
3     1 X 40 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 4032 BAGS OF HEXA...               NID         NID
4     2 X 20 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 160 DRUMS OF GALI...               NID         NID
...                                                 ...               ...         ...
3332  4 X 20 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 4 TANK OF DIMETIL...               NID         NID
3333  5 X 40 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 5040 CARTONS OF G...               NID         NID
3334  5 X 40 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 5040 CARTONS OF G...               NID         NID
3335  1 X 20 & 1 X 20 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 2 TANK O...               NID         NID
3336  3 X 20 CONTAINERS CONTAINING 240 DRUMS OF ENVI...               NID         NID

[3337 rows x 3 columns]
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Obrigado, Paulo! Ajudou muito!